# input type="radio" elements inside an input-group with an input-group-addon

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When creating an `input-group` that contains an `input-group-addon` and `<input type="radio">` elements, the styling of the radio elements looks extremely odd.  Is there a better way to this styling?

```
<form>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">
    <input name="catalog.tecdoc_webservice_enabled_is_nonblank" type="checkbox" value="true" checked=""></span>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="tecdoc_webservice_enabled" type="radio" value="true" checked="">enabled</label>
    <label class="radio-inline"><input name="tecdoc_webservice_enabled" type="radio" value="false">disabled</label>
  </div>
 </form>
```

[image: rendered bootstrap]

https://www.bootply.com/EtjEb4QOGV

Answer (score 1):

It looks like simply adding a `<div class="form-control">` around the radio inputs works great:

https://www.bootply.com/lbtAbZ1bIR#

```
<div class="container">
<form>
  <div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">

    <input name="catalog.tecdoc_webservice_enabled_is_nonblank" type="checkbox" value="true" checked=""></span>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input name="catalog.tecdoc_webservice_enabled" type="radio" value="true" checked="">enabled</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input name="catalog.tecdoc_webservice_enabled" type="radio" value="false">disabled</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div><!-- /.container -->
```

[image]